# How might I summarize the sum of all columns in a filtered dataset using dplyr?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble getting the sum of a column from a filtered dataset. Would someone be able to show me where I am going wrong? This summarize method worked before, but now I get an error. Thank you,

````
  select("STNAME", "CTYNAME", "YEAR", "AGEGRP", "TOT_POP", "TOT_MALE", "TOT_FEMALE")
  save(popSample, file="./datafiles/popSample.rdata" )

load("./datafiles/popSample.rdata")

# We want to see Total Population for all years and all age groups
set1filter <- popSample %>%
  filter(AGEGRP == 0) %>%
  summarize(set1filter, set1 = sum(TOT_POP))
set1```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra `%>%` at the end of `filter` while creating the `set1filter` or remove the `set1filter` from the `summarize` if we are using the same chain

```
library(dplyr)
popSample %>%
      filter(AGEGRP == 0) %>% 
      summarise(set1 = sum(TOT_POP))
```

---

We can't have an object that  is not yet created in the `summarize`

Comment: Would this work then? 
`set1filter <- popSample %>%
      filter(AGEGRP == 0)
set1 <- summarise(set1filter, sum(TOT_POP))`

Comment: @JacksonWalker  That should work.  Here, you in `sum(TOT_POP)` you are not naming the column i.e. `set1 <- summarise(set1filter, SumTOT_POP = sum(TOP_POP))`